# How can I request pinpoint accurate geocoding data using HERE Api

Tags: here-api

I am looking to use HEREs geocoding service to locate the Lat and Lon of a place based on a UK postcode. At the moment my request will return a rough location even though I have provided a full postcode.

The old "geocode" API that I used previously, would return relevant results however this has been put into maintenance and replaced with the "geocode and search" API. This new API seems like it just looks through a list of stored points of interest within HERE’s database and returns the closest it can to what you have searched for, rather than trying to find the exact location entered.

How can I get more accurate results using the below request? Bare in mind that I will only have access to the postcode.

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q={postCode}&apiKey={key}
```

At the moment I receive a response similar to the below using postcode PE1 1QL. It should be pointing to a car park, however if you enter the lat and lon returned from the API into a map E.g Google Maps, it gives you a more general location, rather than an accurate one.

```
{
    "title": "PE1 1, Peterborough, England",
    "id": "here:cm:namedplace:22221149",
    "resultType": "locality",
    "localityType": "postalCode",
    "address": {
        "label": "PE1 1, Peterborough, England",
        "countryCode": "GBR",
        "countryName": "England",
        "county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "city": "Peterborough",
        "postalCode": "PE1 1"
    },
    "position": {
        "lat": 52.57362,
        "lng": -0.24219
    },
    "mapView": {
        "west": -0.23515,
        "south": 52.56739,
        "east": -0.25194,
        "north": 52.57984
    },
    "scoring": {
        "queryScore": 0.67,
        "fieldScore": {
            "postalCode": 0.95
        }
    }
},
```

I would expect the Lat and Lng to be much closer to the postcode entered than the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding on this release notes https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/release_notes/topics/known-issues.html
you can read "High precision postal codes are not yet supported":

**Known Issues**

The following table lists issues known to be present in the current release.

Search for intersections is not yet supported

Search by telephone numbers is not yet supported

Political views are not yet supported. All views are “International”

Places detail views are not yet supported

**High precision postal codes are not yet supported**

---

The Geocoder API 6.2 will be supported at least until end of 2020 (maybe more) and "Maintenance" in documentation means: no new features.